# Progress bar displaying processed data percentage

Tags: php, ajax, forms, progress-bar

I am working on a PHP application that has a template, functions,api structure and I am facing the following problem:

In a tpl I have a html form through which the user may upload a bunch of data. I take the data an send them over to the functions file to process them and then display the results to the user. What I want to achieve is a progress bar that displays the percentage of the processed data to the user through a bootstrap modal and progress bar.

When I submit the form through the html way the page starts to load immediately
thus I cannot update the modal data (trying to do it with a query call from the functions file).

When I do it the query post way because the processing is asynchronous not only the modal is not being updated but when the next page loads the session is not updated either.

Is there an other way around to do this? The only way I have made the progress bar is through the xhr way but this is done in the tpl layer and does not represent the actual data processed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could do it through aJax.

Answer (score 0):

Bind this function to your button instead of using the submit method, and then you can dynamically rebuild your progress bar with the information contained in the response.

```
function build_progress_bar() {

        var SendInfo= {     "info":stuff };

        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://yoursite.com/your_php_script.php',
                data: SendInfo,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    var html = buildProgressBar(data);
                    function buildProgressBar(info) {
                        // Build your Progress bar HTML here
                        return progressBar;
                    }
                    document.getElementById("YOUR_PROGRESS_BAR_CONTAINER").innerHTML = html;

                }
        });

}
```

Note:  You will need jQuery included to use aJax.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I had already tried this. My problem here is that the data is returned once after the processing has ended. In my php script I do have multiple echos where I return the percentage but the data variable only contains the final "true" response.

Comment: Call another aJax function inside the Ajax sucess call then, and either break your php script up into multiple scripts so you can detect the "steps" or add a switch to it so you can call it with a step ID incrementally rather than calling the whole script at once.  Then you can return a new percentage every step of the process